# Improving compile time on a project with thousands of java files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compile-time

Any advice on how to reduce build/compile time on a project which has close to 10k java files ?
On intelliJ it takes around 20 mins with better computing resources [Mac machine, 2Gig heap allocated].
Note: Since this is a test application with each file considered as different test, can't reduce the number of files.

Comment: I think there is no way to reduce time.since num of files are huge so it will take this much time

Comment: With that many files, all you can do is schedule a build every day at lunchtime.  How long does it take to run the test suite?

Comment: Do you use Maven/Gradle?

Comment: I use Maven for build

Answer (score 0):

If you are using external build systems (Maven/Gradle/sbt) to build the project, refer to these build systems documentation and recommendations. As in this case, all building logic if delegated to these build systems.

If you use IDE's builder there are general recommendations to speed up the buid time:

1. If the project is very big increase the heap size for the Build process: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Shared build process heap size (Mbytes):
2. If Kotlin is not used, it makes sense to disable the Kotlin plugin
3. Enable Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Compile independent modules in parallel option
4. One may also consider using the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Build project automatically option
5. If you have antivirus/firewall it also makes sense to exclude IDE settings directories, IDE installation home and project files are excluded from the scan and generally all files and folders used by compiler, JDK and libraries, used in project. See also https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006298560